# coordinates and heading direction relative to one point, rotating a map (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, vector, coordinates, angle, direction

[image: data description] I painted a scheme/diagram that makes it easier to understand my question. (The angles are for technical reasons 0° 90° 180° ... MSpaint won't rotate degreewise, but my data does). I need the B arrows relative to A, concerning the coordinate and relative angle. I subtract A's coordinates from A and B, now A always sits at (0,0) and B keeps its relative distance. How can I do that with the angles of the arrows?

The data I have is situation 1,2 and 3.

I have A and B's coordinates and directions. I need to translate/rotate/normalize/egocentric - whatever the right word might be, to get to situation 4,5 and 6 respectively. In the end, all data (4,5,6) pooled will look like 7, with the new coordinates and directions of B, because then A would always be in the center and heading up. I would believe that something like that might be used often in a different context and am hoping for a inline function or hint/topic to search in.

Comment: So you have 1 and want 4? Please give an example, how are the arrows defined?

Comment: Yes, I have sit1 and I want sit4! for each scenario I have a x y and angle, so for situation 1 (1, 2, 90; 3,2,0), situation 2 (1,2,270; 3,1,0) ... and so on (up beeing 0° and the coordiant system in each black frame is from 0 to 3) the arrows have a middlepoint, the coordiants I have, and a direction (angle in degree) relative to the system, I want the angle of B relativ to A.

Comment: Please put the data you have into your question, using valid matlab syntax.

Comment: x = [1 3; 2 3; 1 3];
y = [2 2; 3 1; 1 1];
angle = [90 0; 270 0; 0 0]; x(:,1) is A's. x(:,2) is B's and so forth

Comment: Have you tried a rotation matrix?

Comment: I looked it up and that migth be it. Awesome! The angles of B I can get by substracting As angle. I will try tomorrow morning. Thanks